# implement custom authorization for anonymous users of a website

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-4.5

How do i implement custom authorization for anonymous users? Basically i want my business layer to check if current request by an anonymous user has access to a specific request.

The anonymous user will get access using a temporary token.

I use form authentication and have implemented custom principle for  the logged in user.

Should i use an AnonymousBase Principle as a default security principle and then have my existing custom security principle inherit from it? I also want to support authenticated users to access resources using a token?

Comment: Have you looked into a custom membershipprovider, roleprovider, etc?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx

Comment: Does it support authorization for anonymous users?

Comment: It supports whatever you build into it.  The default ASP.NET membership provider seems to not support this -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy%28v=vs.98%29.aspx.  However, you could have a link on the login page that the user can click to continue anonymously, then create a unique token for them.  That would be good until the token times out or the user clears their cookies.

Comment: @Parth Trivedi I've noticed that you have suggested a number of edits (including this one) that are misusing the format syntax. Please do not highlight seemingly arbitrary words with bold or code syntax formatting.